Azure Devops Repository Empty After Unpack Pipeline
I am trying to create a pipeline to move my Power Apps solutions to Dev Ops. I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQe7n62RRNU and have gotten the pipeline to run successfully but there are no files in me repository.
The screenshot below shows my process thusfar.

My CMD is the following:
echo commit all changes
git config user. Email “$(UserEmail)”
git config user.name "Automatic Build"
git checkout -b main
git add --all
git commit -m "$(CommitMessage)"
echo push code to new repo
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push origin main

The pipeline runs but the only file in my repo is the readme.
Please, let me know what other information is needed and thanks for you time.

Why are you using a command line task to checkout the code? You can configure all settings related to source control if you click on Get sources above Agent job 1.

Based on your description, the requirements for the workflow are to Export solution from your Power App Environment -> Unpack the solution -> Push the extracted contents to the pipeline source repo. Here is the sample pipeline for your reference.

Make sure the solution is extracted to $(Build.SourcesDiretory), which is the path on the pipeline agent machine and where the pipeline checks out the source code from the repo (an empty repo with only ReadMe.md file);

To use the $(System.AccessToken) of the pipeline service account as the authentication of the git commands in the PowerShell script, we need to first check Allow scripts to access the OAuth token option of the Agent job and grant Contribute permission for the pipeline service account to push to source repo;


Inline PowerShell script
Write-Host "================1. Show contents in Build.SourcesDirectory: ================"
tree $(Build.SourcesDirectory) /F /A

Write-Host "================2. Push the exported solutions to source repo: ================"
git config --global user.email “$(Build.RequestedForEmail)”
git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
git checkout -b $(Build.SourceBranchName)
git add .
git commit -m "Solution exported by $(Build.DefinitionName) in build $(Build.BuildId)"
git push origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)



If you would simply use the repo as a temporary storage to keep the downloaded solutions and extracted contents, you may also consider publishing the files as pipeline artifacts;


The pipeline and its script have used several pipeline predefined variables, please take reference to this document to help understand the workflow.

